# What's wrong with this shell tests?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

In a script that has this functions defined:

```
#!/bin/bash --

outtrue  (){ printf "%15s is T|%s" "$*" "$?"; }
outfalse (){ printf "%15s is F|%s" "$*" "$?"; }

tval1(){  [ "$@" ]  && outtrue "$@" || outfalse "$@"; }
tval2(){  [ "$*" ]  && outtrue "$@" || outfalse "$@"; }
tval3(){ [[ "$@" ]] && outtrue "$@" || outfalse "$@"; }

tval(){
    printf "test %s\t" "$1"; shift
    case $1 in
        (1) shift; tval1 "$@" ;;
        (2) shift; tval2 "$@" ;;
        (3) shift; tval3 "$@" ;;
    esac
    printf "\n"
}
```

This tests work perfectly well (as expected):

```
xyz="str";  tval "-n var"       1   "-n" "$xyz"
xyz="str";  tval "-z var"       1   "-z" "$xyz"
one=1;      tval "1 -eq \$one"  1   "1" "-eq" "$one"
one=2;      tval "1 -eq \$one"  1   "1" "-eq" "$one"
```

Results:

```
test -n var              -n str is T|0
test -z var              -z str is F|1
test 1 -eq $one         1 -eq 1 is T|0
test 1 -eq $one         1 -eq 2 is F|1
```

However, changing "$@" to "$*" or using bash test `[[...]]` makes the
tests fail (note that here either function 2 or 3  is used) :

```
one=1;  tval "1 -eq \$one"  2   "1" "-eq" "$one"
one=2;  tval "1 -eq \$one"  2   "1" "-eq" "$one"

one=1;  tval "1 -eq \$one"  3   "1" "-eq" "$one"
one=2;  tval "1 -eq \$one"  3   "1" "-eq" "$one"
```

Results:

```
test 1 -eq $one         1 -eq 1 is T|0
test 1 -eq $one         1 -eq 2 is T|0

test 1 -eq $one         1 -eq 1 is T|0
test 1 -eq $one         1 -eq 2 is T|0
```

Do you see what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The Quoting!!

With the "$*" and bash `[[...]]` the command line values do not get split.

The tests are equivalent to `[ word ]` were word is not empty, and thus True.